# Insert rows for missing weeks in r

Tags: r

For a large data set I am trying to insert missing weeks for each each customer ID with their corresponding amount to be 0. The week starts from w3 and goes up to w7.

```
df <- data.frame(cust_id = c("111","111","222","222","222","333","333","333","333"),
             week = c("w4","w5","w4","w5","w6","w3","w4","w5","w6"),
             amount = c(23,34,10,12,35,12,23,15,56))


cust_id week amount
  111   w4     23
  111   w5     34
  222   w4     10
  222   w5     12
  222   w6     35
  333   w3     12
  333   w4     23
  333   w5     15
  333   w6     56
```

For e.g. cust_id: 111, w3,w6 and w7 is missing. I want to insert those missing weeks and corresponding amount = 0 for cust_id 111 as shown below.

```
cust_id week amount
  111   w3      0
  111   w4     23
  111   w5     34
  111   w6      0
  111   w7      0
```

Any help would be great,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::complete` :

```
tidyr::complete(df, cust_id, week = paste0('w', 3:7), fill = list(amount = 0))

#   cust_id week  amount
#   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 111     w3         0
# 2 111     w4        23
# 3 111     w5        34
# 4 111     w6         0
# 5 111     w7         0
# 6 222     w3         0
# 7 222     w4        10
# 8 222     w5        12
# 9 222     w6        35
#10 222     w7         0
#11 333     w3        12
#12 333     w4        23
#13 333     w5        15
#14 333     w6        56
#15 333     w7         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the missing combinations with `expand.grid` and then join them :

```
customers <- unique(df$cust_id)
weeks <- paste0("w",3:7)

weeks <- data.frame(expand.grid(customers,weeks))
colnames(weeks) <- c("cust_id","week")
library(dplyr)
left_join(weeks,df) %>% mutate(across(everything(),replace_na,replace=0))

Joining, by = c("cust_id", "week")
   cust_id week amount
1      111   w3      0
2      222   w3      0
3      333   w3     12
4      111   w4     23
5      222   w4     10
6      333   w4     23
7      111   w5     34
8      222   w5     12
9      333   w5     15
10     111   w6      0
11     222   w6     35
12     333   w6     56
13     111   w7      0
14     222   w7      0
15     333   w7      0
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a way using pivots:

```r
df %>% pivot_wider( names_from=week, values_from=amount ) %>%
    mutate( across(matches("^w\\d"), replace_na, replace=0 ), w7=0 ) %>%
    pivot_longer( cols = matches("^w\\d"), names_to="week", values_to="value" ) %>%
    arrange( cust_id, week )
```

Output:

```
   cust_id week  value
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
 1 111     w3        0
 2 111     w4       23
 3 111     w5       34
 4 111     w6        0
 5 111     w7        0
 6 222     w3        0
 7 222     w4       10
 8 222     w5       12
 9 222     w6       35
10 222     w7        0
11 333     w3       12
12 333     w4       23
13 333     w5       15
14 333     w6       56
15 333     w7        0
```